# Python - как задать имя программе?

Tags: python

Делаю Python приложение, и нужно сделать так, что бы имя приложения было написано здесь(скриншот)[image: **введите сюда описание изображения**]

Comment: Первое что требует уточнения. Приложение консольное или с GUI?

Comment: вот решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330393/how-to-set-the-program-title-in-python

Comment: примите ответ, если он вам помог(галочка около ответа)

Answer (score 1):

Windows:

```
import os
title = "something..."
os.system(f"title {title}")
```

*nix:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("\x1b]2;Another Title\x07")
```

Comment: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330393/how-to-set-the-program-title-in-python)

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает (вид заголовка окна в частности), что у автора вопроса Windows, и этот вариант у него не заработает.

Comment: @insolor Точно, я уж привык к таким штукам( у меня мак). Сейчас добавлю вариант для windows(на крестик справа и не обратил внимания)